# Check whether a pointer points to a empty space on a int array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So, I've got a assignment that asks for me to compare 2 arrays of integers (a[5] and b[8]) and check for repeated elements using pointers.
So far, here's the code I came up with:

```
int main(void) {
    int *pa, i, j, sizeA=5, sizeB=8, a[sizeA], b[sizeB], aux[sizeB];
    for (i=0; i<sizeA; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (i=0; i<sizeB; i++){
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
    for (i=0; i<sizeB; i++){
        aux[i] = NULL;
    }
    for(i=0;i<sizeA; i++){
        for(j=0; j<sizeB; j++){
            if ((a[i] == b[j]))
                aux[i] = b[j];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<sizeA; i++){
        pa = &aux[i];
        if ((pa != NULL)&&(*pa!=aux[i+1])){
            printf("%d \n", *pa);
        }
    }


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It got compiled and run without errors, but when there are no repeated elements, the last for Loop prints strange values such as 435304.

I tried to make the pointer "pa" scan through the array "aux", and only print elements that are different from the next one on the array, and check if the position the pointer is pointing is empty.

Any tips?

EDIT: I solved it initializing the aux array with NULL values. Does it count as a valid solution? Is there a better way to do it?

EDIT2: Thanks to everybody that helped me. Have a nice day.

Comment: These are the garbage values...

Comment: As I understand it the benefit of using pointers for this assignment is not having to allocate in advance the size of aux.

Comment: Assigning `NULL` to an integer sets it to `0`. So is `0` a valid value for `a`'s and `b`'s entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only write what's equal on `aux`, which means that the contents of `aux` will be a subset of the contents of B, but you're declaring it with `sizeB` size **and not initilizing it's contents.** This means that on creation, the contents of `aux` are all memory garbage. Because, by the subset definition, you'll leave positions of `aux` without writting (unless A = B), the unwritten positions stay unwritten and so end up containing gargabe. Initialize it to avoid the problem:

```
int myArray[10] = { -1 }; //all elements to -1
```

And stop iterating upon finding a `-1`, or whatever other value you want to use to mark the empty positions.

Comment: What if no integer value may be used to mark an empty position, as the full ranage of integers might be used as input?

Comment: Then declare an int count = 0, increase it by one every time you find a match, then use this count as the iteration limit in the last loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `aux` is a stack symbol. Taking the address it offsetted `&aux[i]` will always return non `NULL` because it is on the stack. You are taking the address of a predefined array element.

If your intention is to save a pointer in `aux` then you need to define it as an array of `int *`

```
int * aux[sizeB];
memset(aux, 0, sizeof(aux)); // don't forget to initialise it
```

And when you assign it you assign the address there.

```
for(i=0;i<sizeA; i++){
        for(j=0; j<sizeB; j++){
            if ((a[i] == b[j]))
                aux[i] = &b[j];
        }
    }
```

And in your loop just read the address:

```
for(i=0;i<sizeA; i++){
        pa = aux[i];
        if ((pa != NULL)&&(*pa!=*(aux[i+1]))){
            printf("%d \n", *pa);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was only aiming at making the pointer pa point to each and every occupied position on the aux array. I could solve it by initializing the aux array with null values

Comment: @Pedro You could, but then `if (pa != NULL)` is useless. `pa` will never be `NULL`. Also how will you then account for zero values in `a` and `b`? If you initialise `aux` with `0` (not `NULL` please unless it's an array of pointers) then how will you distinguish repeating zeroes in `a,b` from initialised zeroes?

Answer (score 0):

You should initize aux correctly (c doesn't fill arrays with zeros by default, that's where your strange values come from) and add a counter that counts the numbers of matches you found instead of using `i < sizeA` in that last loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are copying data from `b` to `aux`.

```
if ((a[i] == b[j]))
```

states that if it is true then copy data.  So tell us what are your input?

Since you are not getting common data in both arrays. It is printing Garbage values.

For solution :

Just provide same data in both arrays, and you will get your output.

Answer (score 0):

aux has values which are default

First set all values of aux to 0 or run a counter till the place where aux has been filled